# app.component.html is Not Rendering in Angular App

Tags: angular

I am trying to get my first Angular app set up and it just isn't loading the app.component.html

I checked for html tags inside app.component.html, my versions are up to date (8.3.18 and typescript 3.5.3), and the selector tags are inside the index.html file at the right place.

If anyone could take a look, I sure would appreciate it.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>ToDo</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body class="m-1">
  <todo-app>Angular placeholder</todo-app>
</body>

</html>
```

apps.component.html:

```
<h3 class="bg-primary p-1 text-white">{{ getName() }}'s To Do List</h3>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr><th></th><th>Description</th><th>Done</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of getTodoItems(); let i = index">
        <td>{{ i + 1 }}</td> /* {} DataBindings */
        <td>{{ item.action }}</td>
        <td [ngSwitch]="item.done">
        <span *ngSwitchCase="true">Yes</span>
        <span *ngSwitchDefault>No</span>
        </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Model } from "./model";
@Component({
  selector: "todo-app",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html"
  })
export class AppComponent {
  model = new Model();
  getName() {
    return this.model.user;
  }

  getTodoItems() {
    return this.model.items;
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

model.ts:

```
export class Model {
    user;
    items;
    constructor() {
        this.user = "Adam";
        this.items = [new TodoItem("Buy Flowers", false),
        new TodoItem("Get Shoes", false),
        new TodoItem("Collect Tickets", false),
        new TodoItem("Call Joe", false)]
    }
}
export class TodoItem {
    action;
    done;
    constructor(action, done) {
        this.action = action;
        this.done = done;
    }
}
```

angular.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "todo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/todo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "todo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "todo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "todo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "todo:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "todo:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "todo"
}
```

polyfills.ts:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 */
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 * because those flags need to be set before `zone.js` being loaded, and webpack
 * will put import in the top of bundle, so user need to create a separate file
 * in this directory (for example: zone-flags.ts), and put the following flags
 * into that file, and then add the following code before importing zone.js.
 * import './zone-flags.ts';
 *
 * The flags allowed in zone-flags.ts are listed here.
 *
 * The following flags will work for all browsers.
 *
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 * (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 * (window as any).__zone_symbol__UNPATCHED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames
 *
 *  in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 *  with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 *
 *  (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;
 *
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Thanks again, y'all!

Comment: I’m seeing a routerModule, but no router outlet... unless I’m missing it..?

Comment: I added the app-routing.module.ts to the bottom. :)

Comment: It seems you changed a lot. Usually, index.html contains the app-root (which is bootstrapped from main.ts). That is missing. Then if you use routing (not sure what’s in your routingModule), you’d expect to have a router outlet somewhere (usually inside your app.component.html) - this also seems to be missing. You might want to consider starting with a fresh app amd make only gradual changes?

Comment: I’d have a look at main.ts.. see what you’re actually bootstrapping?

Comment: added to the bottom, sir

Comment: I don't see a router-outlet.  Just curious, how did you add so much code with the template etc without seeing progress? Was the router added as an afterthought?

Comment: It's from Angular 6 Pro by Adam Freeman

Comment: Only thing I’m seeing is that templateUrl should probably be ./app.component.html

Comment: Naw. It doesn't work, my friend. Angular seems to be kind of a patchworky framework atm... :)

Comment: just an update. I got it working after reverting to a non-routing installation and updating my jquery and popper. (since I was using bootstrap) I think it would have worked if I would have put <router-outlet></router-outlet> and the end of my component.ts file and fixing the bootstrap issue. I appreciate all the help.